# Django: change model value if associated to other model

Tags: python, django, model

I have two models: VehicleForm and Vehicle. I created a field in VehicleForm using the other Vehicle model as a ForeignKey.

```
CHOICES = (
  (0, 'Yes'),
  (1, 'No'),
)

class VehicleForm(models.Model):
    ...
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey('Vehicle', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    ...
    available = models.BooleanField(choices=CHOICES, default=0)
```

When I create a record for VehicleForm and associate a vehicle to that form, I want to mark that particular vehicle's availability as 'No' once the form is valid.

How do I go about this?

Comment: A `Vehicle` can only have one related `VehicleForm`? If that's the case you should probably use a `OneToOneField`

Comment: Or no relation at all, and store it in the parent object. It also is a bit odd that a model ends with `Form`. A model does not focus on what to ask the user, it focusses on storing the data effectively.

Comment: The way I'm conceptualising it is: For this particular vehicle application/transport (VehicleForm) I'm going to assign this Vehicle. That vehicle can no longer be assigned to any other application.". The result from that is also when I search for available cars that does not return in that result.